# Identifying Compression Ratio in a ECW raster file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, compression

I'm trying to identify and verify the compression ratio of an ecw raster file and I cannot find the information under properties > source tab. I'm trying to using ArcMap 10.5 to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression ratio is not saved into metadata of ECW but it is not at all difficult to calculate it by yourself. You can see the compressed size of the image from your file system, and the size as uncompressed bytes comes from formula

```
(width) x (height) x (band count) x (bit depth/8)
```

Comment: GDALInfo will give you the COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET= in the metadata fields. This does not mean the target has been hit, the file may be slightly smaller or larger than the target. The formula you state is the *actual* file size, uncompressed, without headers. If you are attempting to calculate precisely you must remove the header but there is no way to gain the header size, which for ECW files is quite significant.